# Class template: default constructor argument to cause diagnostic error. Is undefined behavior?

Tags: c++11

While working on a library I found a code that can be summarized in this snippet:

```
struct MainStream{} default_stream, custom_stream;
struct Stream2{} custom_stream2;

template <class StreamSelection>
class Manage {
    public:
    Manage(StreamSelection & out_stream = default_stream){ 
        // do something
    };
};

void test(void) {
    Manage <MainStream> s1_a; //ok: use default_stream
    Manage <MainStream> s1_b(default_stream); //ok: use default_stream
    Manage <MainStream> s1_c(custom_stream); //ok: use custom_stream
    Manage <Stream2> s2_a(custom_stream2); //ok: use custom_stream2
    //Manage <Stream2> s2_b; //diagnostic error if uncommented due the incompatible default argument.
}
```

The purpose of such a constructor is to provide a default argument if the template is instantiated with `MainStream`, ALSO to force a diagnostic error for other parameters in case of a not provided constructor argument and ALSO to avoid any additional template specialization to reach the purpose.

That said, the snippet compiles and works as intended with GCC (-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra), CLANG and MSVC.

Keeping out considerations regarding the style of the code, the question is: does this thing involve undefined behavior ?

The only reference I'm able to find in inside the ISO paper N3337 (final C++11 working draft) at 14.7.1 point 3:

> Unless a call is to a function template explicit specialization or to
> a member function of an explicitly specialized class template, a
> default argument for a function template or a member function of a
> class template is implicitly instantiated when the function is called
> in a context that requires the value of the default argument.

but I'm not sure this match (the question is about the type of the default argument, not the its instance.)
Any suggestion ?

EDIT: To clarify, when the class is instantiated with a parameter other than "MainStream" the ignored default argument has anyway an incompatible type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[temp.inst/1]** The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, but not of the definitions **or default arguments**, of the class member functions...

Emphasis mine. Plus the passage you've already found:

> **[temp.inst/3]** .. a default argument for a function template or a member function of a class template is implicitly instantiated when the function is called **in a context that requires the value of the default argument**.

The rules are designed to make the code like your work, by postponing the instantiation of the default argument as late as possible, in the hopes that it wouldn't be needed.

Comment: This explain everything. Thank you.